# PHPMailer with body contents generated on the fly

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

So I'm using PHPMailer to send an email to a user database once a week using my web host's scheduled tasks. However, the contents of the email need to be generated at run-time when the scheduled task runs.

In my code, I create the HTML contents, generate the HTML file and save it into a directory on the server, then try to use that newly created HTML file as the email's body contents.

However, when I run the page I get:

`Mailer Error (xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx) Message body empty`

Any ideas how to resolve this? Code below:

```
$emailMessage .= "HTML code is in here.";

$fileName = date("YmdHis") . "-email.html";
$newEmail = fopen("path/to/file/$fileName", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($newEmail, $emailMessage);
fclose($newEmail);

$body = file_get_contents('path/to/file/$fileName');

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->msgHTML($body);

etc etc
```

If I hard code in the name of the file in the `$body` line it works, but not when I use the variable name. Anyone know if it's possible or is there a better way to send an email that's generated on the fly?

Comment: Why don't you just do `$mail->msgHTML($emailMessage)` ? Storing it in a file just to immediatley fetch the contents seems needlessly convoluted to me

Comment: I could, and indeed I am at present, but I need to keep a hard copy of the email that's sent. I'm just curious as to why it won't let me use the file.

Comment: Single quotes do not allow the use of inline variables, use double quotes `$body = file_get_contents("path/to/file/$fileName");`

Comment: Even with your reasons for storing it in a file, I would advise against using `file_get_contents` - you already have the data, why add an extra disk read operation to your script?

Comment: Of course! Single quotes (facepalm!). However, Scoots is right, best just to use the $emailMessage variable directly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes matter. Change the single quotes in

```
$body = file_get_contents('path/to/file/$fileName');
```

To double quotes

```
$body = file_get_contents("path/to/file/$fileName");
```

Comment: Yep, facepalm moment! Can't believe I missed that. That's what happens when you copy and paste code (even from PHPMailer's support docs!).

Answer (score 1):

Only using double quotes (") PHP will interpret variable names

Comment: Yep, see above. Can't believe I missed that!!